# size of class nested inside templated class, but not dependent on template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

I have the following code:

```
template < unsigned int Num, class ValueType >

class COuter
{

    public:     
    class CInner
    {

        private:
        CInner* m_pPrev;
        CInner* m_pNext;
        ValueType*  m_pValue;
    }
}
```

The size of CInner is clearly not dependent on template arguments of COuter

Is there a way to do

```
sizeof(COuter::CInner)
```

without having to specify template arguments for COuter?

Thanks!

Comment: make CInner a child class of COuter though it might not help, but it does look better

Comment: "`The size of CInner is clearly not dependent on template arguments of COuter`" hmmm, `ValueType * m_pValue` line looks suspicious.

Comment: It's a pointer, so size of m_pValue doesn't depend on ValueType

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if you make `m_pValue` of type `void*` and cast it to the real type every time you use it.

Comment: Yes it's a pointer if you refer to `COuter` template arguments list. But what would it mean if you left `CInner` alone? How compiler can deduce what you had in mind in such case.

Comment: That still doesn't help, I still have to do sizeof(COuter<arg0, arg1>::CInner) or I get a compiler error. Looking for some clever metaprogramming solution here, i guess...

Comment: `sizeof(COuter<arg0, arg1>::CInner)` is the right thing to do. At some point you may modify `CInner` so that its size depends on template arguments "more" and you will have troubles if you were not explicit about the `CInner` size. You can of course use typedefs or template aliases for common COuter types.

Comment: Yes, right now I am using an alias for a common COuter type, problem is if I ever get rid of it, then I think I will end up with an unused template instantiation. But seems like this is the best solution for now, was just hoping that there was some clever c++ syntax for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Why do you want to be able to do `sizeof(COuter::CInner)`? Preferably with a example that demonstrates why.

Comment: Multiple instances of COuter that also differ by template arguments use one common array of CInner, so the array of CInner gets allocated at app initialization and then later on it gets passed to each COuter ctor, for example.

Comment: And the reason its nested is so that I dont have to do typecasting from void* to ValueType* inside COuter

Comment: @Rincer But you still have to cast from array of `COuter<N1, VT1>::CInner` to array of `COuter<N2, VT2>::CInner`, don't you? And how do you know which `ValueType` each instance of `CInner` in the common array is pointing to?

Comment: Not all pointers are created equal and some pointers are bigger than others. Given that the size of `m_pValue` is absolutely dependent on `ValueType`.

Comment: Yes, I used 'array' for simplicity, but its actually a pooled memory allocator that allocates objects of size CInner, the constructor of the pooled memory allocator is where I need the 'sizeof'. The allocator returns void*, then inside COuter I cast it to CInner*. I guess we are all kind of used to casting the return values of memory allocation calls so I didnt think of it as real 'casting', but you are correct there is a cast involved.

Comment: Sounds like a job for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool .. why not just cast from `void*` to each specialization of `COuter<A, B>::CInner` as required?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I do, but as I mentioned, the memory pool needs to know the size of CInner at initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If type safety when using those pointers is your main concern, then you could do this:

```
class CInnerBase
{
    protected:
    void* m_pPrev;
    void* m_pNext;
    void* m_pValue;
};

template <unsigned int Num, class ValueType>
class COuter
{
    public:     
    class CInner : public CInnerBase
    {
        public:
        ValueType* pValue() { return static_cast<ValueType*>(m_pValue); }
        //and similar for m_pPrev and m_pNext
        //also type-safe constructors and assignment operators
    };
};
```

Your allocator can then just use `CInnerBase`. `COuter` can cast what it gets from the allocator to the appropriate `CInner*` type.

`CInnerBase` could be an inner class of the allocator class.

You may find that some functionality that's not dependent on those template parameters will naturally migrate from the template `CInner` to the non-template `CInnerBase` - not bad for avoiding code bloat.

Also, `m_pPrev` and `m_pNext` could be `CInnerBase*` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to allocate two or more objects with the same layout but with different types, from the same memory pool.

Let's say you're using a memory pool class template similar to this one: https://github.com/cacay/MemoryPool .

```
template<typename T>
struct memory_pool
{
    T* allocate();
    void deallocate(T*);
};
```

In this specific case you can use the `void` specialization of `CInner` as the parameter to your memory pool. This works because it is a POD type which has the same size and alignment requirement as any other specialization of `CInner`.

```
typedef COuter<0, void>::CInner Storage;
typedef memory_pool<Storage> Pool;
```

You can then use the following allocation and deallocation functions which use placement new to convert the POD storage type to the desired type.

```
#include <new>

template<typename T>
T* allocate(Pool& pool)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(Storage));
    static_assert(alignof(T) == alignof(Storage));
    return new (pool.allocate()) T();
}

template<typename T>
void deallocate(Pool& pool, T* p)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(Storage));
    static_assert(alignof(T) == alignof(Storage));
    p->~T();
    pool.deallocate(reinterpret_cast<Storage*>(p));
}

int main()
{
    Pool pool;
    typedef COuter<0, int>::CInner Type;
    Type* p = allocate<Type>(pool);
    deallocate(pool, p);
}
```

If your compiler supports `std::aligned_storage` - a C++11 feature - you can define `Storage` in a more general way which would allow `CInner` to be a non-POD type:

```
#include <type_traits> 

typedef COuter<0, void>::CInner VoidInner;
const std::size_t SIZE = sizeof(VoidInner);
const std::size_t ALIGN = alignof(VoidInner);
typedef std::aligned_storage<SIZE, ALIGN>::type Storage;
```